# Update Gradient in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell with image and button which have a gradient. When I scroll - I have a bug: The gradient is drawn with a new layer on the image, and the text from the button disappears.This happens when I scroll back. I think I should use `override func prepareForReuse()`. But I don't know how to do it.` Perhaps someone could write code that would fix the bug, because I don't know how to do it.

```
import UIKit

class TrainingProgramCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {



private var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
@IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

var trainingPrograms: TrainingProgram? {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}



private func updateUI()
{
    if let trainingProgram = trainingPrograms {
        featuredImageView.image = trainingPrograms!.featuredImage
        titleLabel.text = trainingPrograms!.title
        descriptionLabel.text = trainingPrograms!.description
       // bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
      // buttonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 21/255, green: 126/255, blue: 238/255, alpha: 1)
        buttonOutlet.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.52, blue: 1, alpha: 1), colorTwo:  UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.39, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1), cornerRadius: 25)
        buttonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        buttonOutlet.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
        buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        buttonOutlet.layer.shadowRadius = 15
        buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        bgView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20



        featuredImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        let view = UIView(frame: featuredImageView.frame)
        view.clipsToBounds = true


       // view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        featuredImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = view.frame

        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.48, blue: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor,UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.48, blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.1, 1.0]
        view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        featuredImageView.addSubview(view)
        featuredImageView.bringSubviewToFront(view)





    } else {
        featuredImageView.image = nil
        titleLabel.text = nil
        descriptionLabel.text = nil
    }


}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    layer.shadowRadius = 10
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10)

    self.clipsToBounds = false
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()





}
```

}

Set gradient for Button

```
extension UIView {

func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `UpdateUI()` function, you create new layer using `let gradient = CAGradientLayer()` and ad it as a first children to parent 
        `view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)`

Looks like you should rather have reference for this layer in the cell and only update the parameters

Comment: Thanks, but how to properly apply a gradient to the photo and update it constantly ? Could you write code ? This is my first experience and I do not know how to do it. Thank you :)